# CiviMember Role Sync not Syncing One User

Tags: drupal, civimember, roles

Our Drupal 7.50 website is set up so that users can subscribe through CiviMemberships via a contribute page and then we use CiviMember Role Sync Module to assign them a new Drupal role. This has worked well and thousands have gone through this process. However, we have one user who went through the process of creating a Drupal account and then subscribing (becoming a member) and the sync refuses to sync his accounts. I had to give him the Drupal role manually. Names and email address are the same in his Drupal account and his CiviCRM contact record. The contact record shows his membership and contribution. Any ideas how to troubleshoot or manually sync this one user?

CiviCRM 4.7.15 Drupal 7.50 Commons

Thanks!

Comment: check everything looks right in the uf_match table?

Comment: This problem has come up again, where the User ID is off by one number. What do I look for in the uf_match table to see if it's correct or not?

Comment: I would search for his email in that table, and then see what user id and contact id is connected.

Answer (score 1):

See if there's a deleted contact with the same deets?.

Also petendz's advice is stellar as ever. Use the api explorer do get uf match on that email if for whatever reason you can't access the MySQL table.